# Implement an interface defined in a Library

Tags: java, android

I have my Android Library which defines an Interface for registering the library to get callbacks. I need my application to implement the interface. But this leads to circular dependency, how can this be achieved without invoking circular Dependancy.
Project Structure:

MyApp-/ .
    class LibraryImpl implements interface register .
MyLib-/ .
     interface register .

**Sample Code snippet:**
**MyLib** .

ActivityStarter.java

```
public interface ActivityStarter {
    void startHelpActivity();
}
```

ActivityStarterModule.java

```
public class ActivityStarterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    @ReactMethod
    void navigateToExample() {
       //Start an activity
    }
}
```

**MyApp** .
ActivityStarterImpl.java

```
public class ActivityStarterImpl extends BaseActivity implements ActivityStarter {
    public void startHelpActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

How to trigger a call from navigateToExample in MyLib function to startHelpActivity function in MyApp?

Comment: "But this leads to circular dependency" -- I fail to see this. MyApp depends upon MyLib. MyLib has no reason to depend upon MyApp. MyApp is the one that needs the interface; MyLib does not need direct access to any MyApp classes.

Comment: How does myLib get to know which class is implementing the interface? 
I am trying to start an Activity from Library and need to use the class name to start the Activity rather than using an intent filter. I will update the question with code snippet

Comment: Your library should not be the one dictating what activity needs to be started unless that activity is part of the library

Comment: This is actually a part of implementing ReactNative in my existing app. There is a button in JS package which starts an Activity from Native app. For bridging purpose I am using a Library as a Bridge to link between JS module and Android Module. The navigateToExample is called on button press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does myLib get to know which class is implementing the interface?

Option #1: MyApp passes it as a parameter to MyLib. This works the same as how *you* pass it to `Intent`: via a Java `Class` object.

Option #2: The activity has an `<intent-filter>` for some custom implicit `Intent` action. MyLib creates an `Intent` for that implicit `Intent` action and uses `setPackage()` to limit the scope of the `Intent` to the app's own package. Then, start the activity using that `Intent`.

Option #3: The activity has an `<intent-filter>` for some custom implicit `Intent` action. MyLib creates an `Intent` for that implicit `Intent` action and uses `setPackage()` to limit the scope of the `Intent` to the app's own package. Then, look up the activity via `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()`. Use that information to construct an explicit `Intent` (one that has the `ComponentName` of the activity). Then, start the activity using that explicit `Intent`.

Option #4: Don't have two separate modules; have all of this be a single app module. Then, the code formerly in MyLib has direct access to the code formerly in MyApp.

Comment: Option#1 seems to be most useful for my use case. I will try using that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution based on the suggestion provided by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).

MyLib .

ActivityStarter.java

```
public interface ActivityStarter {
    void startHelpActivity();
}
```

ActivityStarterModule.java

```
public class ActivityStarterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ActivityStarter mActivityStarter;
            @ReactMethod
            void navigateToExample() {
               //Start an activity
               mActivityStarter.startHelpActivity();
            }
        }
```

MyApp .
ActivityStarterImpl.java

```
    public class ActivityStarterImpl extends BaseActivity implements ActivityStarter {
        public void startHelpActivity(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


public class BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityStarterModule.mActivityStarterModule = new ActivityStarterImpl() {
            @Override
            public void startHelpActivity() {
                super.startHelpActivity();
            }
        }
    }
```